# 'Undropdown' menu when mobile

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, responsive

I'm testing a responsive dropdown navigation bar I got from W3Schools but I want the possibility of 'undropdrowning' when the navbar is shown on a mobile. Right now, when on mobile, the menu-items are displayed on top of eachother and you have the possibility to dropdown 'ONS AANBOD'. But then, the submenu is displayed all over the other following links. So if you don't want to visit the submenu or you misclicked, you can't just click on a following menu-item. I want to be able to click again on the menu-item so the submenus close again. Thanks!

```
<div class="col-12 navbar-0">
    <div class="col-10 col-center-block col-container w3-bar w3-light-grey">
        <a href="index.php" class="colom col-3 home w3-bar-item w3-button">
            <strong>HOME</strong>
        </a>
        <div class="w3-dropdown-hover colom col-3">
            <button class="aanbod w3-button"><strong>ONS AANBOD</strong>
            </button>
            <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block col-3 w3-card-4">
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">WebDesign</a>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Retoucheren</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="index.php" class="colom col-3 portfolio w3-bar-item w3-button">
            <strong>PORTFOLIO</strong>
        </a>
        <a href="index.php" class="colom col-3 contact w3-bar-item w3-button">
            <strong>CONTACT</strong>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("demo");
        if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
            x.className += " w3-show";
        } else {
            x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: "I want to do X" questions are not a good fit for stack overflow. We're not a free code-writing service.

Comment: I'm sorry, it isn't my intention to freeload on others, but I'm relatively new to WebDesign and especially JavaScript, that's why I asked this question.

Comment: No problem. The best thing to do would be try something yourself. Maybe that involves writing a bespoke solution, maybe it involves finding a JavaScript library designed to solve this problem and integrating it with your current menu. If you get stuck during that process, **then** it's a good time to ask a question :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip :)

Comment: You're welcome. This might be of interest: http://lukaszfiszer.github.io/selectnav.js/index.html